# how to convert c/c++ GUID type to C#?

Tags: c#, guid

i have a c/c++ function:

```
BOOL __stdcall Plat_GetAllCameraInfoEx(GUID guid)
```

Is it possible to convert directly to System.Guid in C#?if not,what should I do?

Comment: [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373931(v=vs.85).aspx) is probably a good starting point.

Comment: thanks for you help.in the case,i fixed it.but,another c/c++ style function prototype:
`GUID __stdcall Plat_GetVersion()`
always return pinvoke error